# Finding document containing array of nested names in pymongo (CrossRef data)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nested-fields

I have a dataset of [CrossRef works records](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) stored in a collection called `works` in MongoDB and I am using a Python application to query this database.

I am trying to find documents based on one author's name. Removing extraneous details, a document might look like this:

```
{'DOI':'some-doi',
'author':[{'given': 'Albert','family':'Einstein',affiliation:[]},
{'given':'R.','family':'Feynman',affiliation:[]},
{'given':'Paul','family':'Dirac',affiliation:['University of Florida']}]
}
```

It isn't clear to me how to combine the queries to get just Albert Einstein's papers.

I have indexes on author.family and author.given, I've tried:

```
cur = works.find({'author.family':'Einstein','author.given':'Albert'})
```

This returns all of the documents by people called 'Albert' and all of those by people called 'Einstein'. I can filter this manually, but it's obviously less than ideal.

I also tried:

```
cur = works.find({'author':{'given':'Albert','family':'Einstein','affiliation':[]}})
```

But this returns nothing (after a very long delay). I've tried this with and without 'affiliation'. There are a few questions on SO about querying nested fields, but none seem to concern the case where we're looking for 2 specific things in 1 nested field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `author` is a list.

You can use an aggregate query to unwind this list to objects, and then your query would work:

```
cur = works.aggregate([{'$unwind': '$author'},
                       {'$match': {'author.family':'Einstein', 'author.given':'Albert'}}])
```

Alternatively, use `$elemMatch` which matches on arrays that match all the elements specified.

```
cur = works.find({"author": {'$elemMatch': {'family': 'Einstein', 'given': 'Albert'}}})
```

Also consider using [multikey indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This seems to work, but it is timing out on my dataset (>100m documents). Is there anything I could do to make it faster?

Comment: I've added some more options to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is working a lot better now.